# Complex Valued function differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ where z is a complex variable, is it true that $f'(z)=u'(z)+iv'(z)$?

Comment: What work have you attempted so far?

Comment: Are $u$ and $v$ the real/imaginary parts? It's unlikely that they are complex-differentiable.

Comment: Unless $u$ and $v$ are holomorphic functions $u'(z)$ and $v'(z)$ are **undefined**.